# What is causing this invalid token error?

Tags: android, xml

In android studio, I have changed my main activity XML file name and when I compile my application I get this error:

> AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:xlmns="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xlmns:="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    >
    <TextView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>

...
```

Comment: Please share you XML here

Comment: Share your XML and main activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there is error in your xml during compilation.

1. Possibly an extra character.
2. Extra spacing.
3. Any closing tag missing,  etc

These are common cases i have mentioned. If your share the xml can help you furthur.

Replace the below line in xml you are missing tools

```
 xlmns:="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

with

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

You can read more about this XML namespace here:https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html

Hope this helps you.....